# The matrix is ​​invertible when? OBS: The array follows

Tags: matrices

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\sin x & \cos x & 0 & 1 \\
\sin x & \cos x & 0 & 0 \\
\sin x & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Is $A$ invertible?

I tried the method of determining , but only got the following relationship:
$$\det A=-\sin x(1-\cos x)$$

Comment: You need to end math mode with $$

Comment: is $sen x = \sin x$?

Comment: @christina_g, according to [this site](http://www.math.com/tables/trig/es-identities.htm) it does seem so.

Comment: if your detA is correct then clearly it is not invertible if x = 0. how about other x values?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Invertible if and only if determinant is nonzero. When is $-\sin(x)(1-\cos x) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A simple inspection of the matrix shows that it is singular only if $\sin x=0$ because, in this case, the first column has all zero entries. the other three columns are always linear independent.